# How to animate different objects at sametime?

Tags: keynote, animation

I think this is very basic question but I could not find solution online. I have `keynote 7.0` on `OS X EL Capitan 10.11.16`.
The problem is I have 3 objects and I want them to disappear at the same time. I tried to select all of them and put `Build out` animation on it but the objects go 1 by 1. And if I try to change one of the objects order to `1` another changes to that objects value. I was thinking i could put all of them to `1` but not possible. 
I am very lost over this right now.

Comment: Did you try making them into a group, and then assigning the action to the group rather than to individual objects?

Comment: yeah i did that. but if i want to for example, make one disappear and another appear at the same time. that is also not possible.